# how to run listening and recognizer service in background all the time android

Tags: java, android, service, speech-recognition

I want developing app who listent to user every time and when keyword said so doing something. 
for that I used `vosk-api` 
I declaring `IntentService`. currently when user click on swich botton in the bottom navigation the service is stop. How I can run the service all the time in the background something like `ok google`?
the code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Check if user has given permission to record audio
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
        return;
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "RECORD_AUDIO not allowed");
        }
    }
}

public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

private SpeechService speechService;
private Model model;

public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    initRecognizer();

    speechService.addListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPartialResult(String s) {
            Log.d("MyIntentService", s + "\n");
            if (s.contains("me"))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "coollll!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResult(String s) {
            Log.d("MyIntentService", s + "\n");
            if (s.contains("me"))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "coollll!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.d("MyIntentService", "Error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeout() {
            speechService.cancel();
            speechService = null;
            Log.d("MyIntentService", "onTimeout");
        }
    });
    speechService.startListening();

}

public void initRecognizer(){
    Assets assets;
    try {
        assets = new Assets(getApplicationContext());
        File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
        model = new Model(assetDir.toString() + "/model-android");
        KaldiRecognizer rec = new KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000.0f);
        speechService = new SpeechService(rec, 16000.0f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a foreground service that implements `RecognitionListener`. But I started with the `vosk` demo app.

I call `initModel()` inside of `onCreate` method in a service. In the callback of the `initModel` method I call `recognizeMicrophone` method that is the same as in the demo app.